# Azure AD Access Token Without ADAL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to edit a user's AD profile on the server side which requires an access token.  I can do this with the native app example which uses only a client id and secret.  [The docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/) mention that this is possible with only http requests (see Get Access Token), but I can't find any example or way to do this.

Comment: One workaround I can think of is to use Fiddler to track down the http request sent by ADAL and then generate it by yourself.

Comment: This is a fantastic tip.  Helped me solve the problem. Thanks @yonisha.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I got this to work using Jack's answer but with a couple of changes.  Here is the complete working example:

```
$tenantID = "<the name of your tenant of your Azure AD>"
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"
$graphResourceURI = "https://graph.windows.net/"

$clientId = "<the client id of your AD application>"
$key = "<the client secret of your AD application>"

# the URL for requesting access token.
$tokenURL = $loginEndpoint+$tenantID+"/oauth2/token"

# the token request body.
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+$clientId `
         +"&client_secret="+[system.uri]::EscapeDataString($key) `         
         +"&resource="+[system.uri]::EscapeDataString($graphResourceURI)

# the token request headers.
$headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

$authenticationResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST `
                         -Uri $tokenURL -Headers $headers -Body $body

$authenticationResult.access_token
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use OAuth2 to request an access token. Here is an example on how you use OAuth2 with Azure AD. It's written in PowerShell Script.

```
$tenantID = "<the Tenant ID of your Azure AD>"
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"
$graphResourceURI = "https://graph.windows.net/"
$clientId = "<the client id of your AD application>"
$key = "<the client secret of your AD application>"

# the URL for requesting access token.
$tokenURL = $loginEndpoint+$tenantID+"/oauth2/token"

# the token request body.
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+$clientId `
         +"&client_secret="+[system.uri]::EscapeDataString($key) `
         +"&resource="+[system.uri]::EscapeDataString($graphResourceURI)

# the token request headers.
$headers = @{"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

$authenticationResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST `
                         -Uri $tokenURL -Headers $headers -Body $body

$authenticationResult.access_token
```

The AD application you use here must be "Web application and/or web API", because a Native AD application does not have client secret.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. I've tried 2 different sets of client id/secret that work in other places but when I run this script I get an error about validating credentials because the "Invalid client secret is provided."

Comment: I have updated my answer. Well, it's not a good idea to copy someone's answer, do a small editing, and accept it.

Comment: Right. It would've been way better if I had just accepted a broken answer. Also, your example _still_ isn't correct. SubscriptionID is never used in your code and redirect URI isn't required.